# Lending Club is not available to my area. Is it possible to invest via somebody else?

Tags: loans, peer-to-peer-lending, lending-club

I live in DC and can't invest using Lending Club. My brother lives in CA and does. Is there any way to 'gift' him money or any other way to have him invest money for me? I want it to all be legal but would love to find a way to make this work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with why LC isn't available in DC.  If it's just a problem with them, then try Prosper instead (www.prosper.com).  If it's a problem with ALL microfinance programs, then I can't help.

Answer (score 5):

It's perfectly legal for your brother to make a loan to you.  However those two transactions are separate.  If he defaults on the LC loan because you didn't pay him, it's his responsibility.  If you default on your loan with him, you've got big problems.  Money + family/friends = scary.

Comment: (FWIW, the loan would be going the other way, but that doesn't change the substance of your answer.)